# "String calculation not permitted here" is thrown on REDUCE

Tags: for-loop, abap

I have a few field names in `LT_FIELDS`. I am trying to concatenate the data in that internal table in a specific format and append it to `LT_WHERE` for a dynamic select query.

Below is the snippet I wrote:

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_whr,
         fieldname TYPE string,
       END OF ty_whr.

DATA(lt_fields) = VALUE rsds_frange_t( ).
DATA(lt_where) = REDUCE ty_whr(
                   INIT whereclause = VALUE ty_whr( )
                   FOR <fields> IN lt_fields
                   NEXT whereclause = 
                     COND #( WHEN whereclause IS NOT INITIAL
                             THEN <fields>-fieldname && | IN | && |@| && <fields>-fieldname && | AND |
                             ELSE <fields>-fieldname && | IN | && |@| && <fields>-fieldname
                          ) ).
```

I am getting this error on concatenation part:

> `String calculation not permitted here`

Is the syntax wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax messages are a little bit strange with Constructor Expressions.

In fact the issue is due to the target (`whereclause`) which is a structure, you can't assign a Text Literal to a structure, instead you should assign it to its text component `whereclause-fieldname` (right after `NEXT`):

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_whr,
         fieldname TYPE string,
       END OF ty_whr.

DATA(lt_fields) = VALUE rsds_frange_t( ).
DATA(lt_where) = REDUCE ty_whr(
                   INIT whereclause = VALUE ty_whr( )
                   FOR <fields> IN lt_fields
                   NEXT whereclause-fieldname = 
                     COND #( WHEN whereclause IS NOT INITIAL
                             THEN <fields>-fieldname && | IN | && |@| && <fields>-fieldname && | AND |
                             ELSE <fields>-fieldname && | IN | && |@| && <fields>-fieldname
                          ) ).
```

Comment: Hi Sandra, that's right. mentioning the component solved the problem. The above snippet is creating a deep structure `lt_where` with `fieldname`. I have edited my goal in the question. My code doesn't seem to be doing the trick. Can you take a look at it?

Comment: Is it possible that you post another question please? We must keep only one question per question, as per Stack Overflow guidelines, so that future visitors can easily find a precise answer to a precise question. Thank you.

Comment: Sure, will do. Thank you! :)